# Sauf à croire très fortement à Leibniz et à tout ce qui s'ensuit ?

Tags: sens, philosophie

Entendu sur la radio France Inter ce matin, un invité a dit :

> Je suis attaché à la vérité, donc tant que je n'aurai pas la preuve, je ne dirais pas ça. Mais il y a en tout cas une coïncidence - sauf à croire très fortement à Leibniz et à tout ce qui s'ensuit...

Leibniz a développé le calcul différentiel en parallèle de Newton, est-ce que le sous-entendu est que Leibniz mentait, et qu'il n'y avait pas de coïncidence ? Si non, quel est le sous-entendu dans "croire très fortement en Leibniz et tout ce qui s'ensuit" ? Il peut être important de noter que l'invité de ce matin était titulaire d'une licence de philosophie.

Merci d'avance !

Comment: Quel est le contexte ? Ça doit faire référence à une position philosophique de Leibniz, mais sans contexte, difficile de savoir laquelle. Rien à voir avec le calcul différentiel en tout cas. Par ailleurs, où est la question de langue ici ? Le langage de la philosophie fait partie du sujet du site, mais la question m'a l'air de porter purement sur la philosophie elle-même et non sur la manière de l'exprimer.

Comment: @Gilles : L'invité parlait de la coïncidence entre les insinuations/allégations de Marine le Pen pendant le débat présidentiel ("J’espère qu'on ne va pas découvrir que vous avez un compte au Bahamas...") alors que dans le même temps cette rumeur était répandue sur les réseaux sociaux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il me semble que cela se réfère au principe de raison suffisante énoncé par Leibniz :

« Jamais rien n'arrive sans qu'il y ait une cause ou du moins une raison déterminante, c'est-à-dire qui puisse servir à rendre raison a priori pourquoi cela est existant plutôt que non existant et pourquoi cela est ainsi plutôt que de toute autre façon »

Le principe serait alors exagéré jusqu'à estimer qu'il n'y a jamais de coïncidence.

A mes yeux, cela ressemble plus à un trait d'humour de philosophe plutôt qu'à un argument sérieux.

Comment: Merci ! A priori ce n'est pas une coïncidence si ça répond aussi bien à la question.